# Prevent drop down to appear behind another div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a drop down menu [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/war6qcvs/). But it actually drops and disappears behind another div. I tried to fix it with `z-index`, but it didn't help.

```css
div {
  padding: 1px;
}
#pageWrap {
  margin: auto;
  width: 800px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#header {
  background-color: #efefef;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
}
.menu {
  margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.menu li {
  float: left;
}
.menu li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  top: -9999px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.menu li:hover {
  position: relative;
  background: #111;
}
.menu li:hover ul {
  left: 0px;
  top: 40px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #222;
}
.menu li:hover ul li a {
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 168px;
  text-indent: 5px;
}
.menu li:hover ul li a:hover {
  background: #111;
}
#content {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: justify;
}
.title {
  font-size: 2em;
}
.subtitle {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-style: italic;
}
.date {
  color: grey;
}
.articleText {
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}
#footer {
  text-align: center;
}
#bottomBar {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="pageWrap">
    <div id="topBar">
      <p>
        <?php include_once( "php/topBar.php") ?>
      </p>
      <p>Top bar - not currently used, but left here just in case</p>
    </div>

    <div id="header">
      <p>
        <?php include_once( "php/header.php") ?>
      </p>
      <p>Header - Placeholder</p>
    </div>

    <div id="mainMenu">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Navigation</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Subitem 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Subitem 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Subitem 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
      <div class="title">
        This is a title
      </div>

      <div class="subtitle">
        The subtitle might be important
      </div>

      <div class="date">
        2016-01-12
      </div>

      <div class="articleText">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent eu lorem vestibulum, luctus ex sit amet, feugiat tellus. Curabitur et nisl libero. Vestibulum suscipit tempus auris, eget eleifend libero scelerisque nec. Pellentesque in tortor
          ultrices ipsum sodales aliquet in nec arcu.
        </p>
        <p>Quisque blandit scelerisque diam pellentesque tristique. Nunc aliquet hendrerit risus ut pellentesque.
        </p>Nulla quis
        <p>ultricies leo. Nam felis libero, hendrerit ac ante posuere, egestas sagittis leo. Aenean quis accumsan libero, sed bibendum purus. Suspendisse ac tortor et sem vulputate faucibus in sit amet orci. Vestibulum ut dictum massa, in alesuada neque.
          Duis mauris enim, porttitor sit amet mi a, ultricies egestas nisl. Nullam vitae urna efficitur, cursus nisl sit amet, molestie orci. Duis et nulla tortor
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="title">
        This is another article on the site
      </div>

      <div class="subtitle">
        Subtitle comes here
      </div>

      <div class="date">
        2016-01-12
      </div>

      <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent eu lorem vestibulum, luctus ex sit amet, feugiat tellus. Curabitur et nisl libero. Vestibulum suscipit tempus auris, eget eleifend libero scelerisque nec. Pellentesque in tortor
          ultrices ipsum sodales aliquet in nec arcu.
        </p>
        <p>Quisque blandit scelerisque diam pellentesque tristique. Nunc aliquet hendrerit risus ut pellentesque.
        </p>Nulla quis
        <p>ultricies leo. Nam felis libero, hendrerit ac ante posuere, egestas sagittis leo. Aenean quis accumsan libero, sed bibendum purus. Suspendisse ac tortor et sem vulputate faucibus in sit amet orci. Vestibulum ut dictum massa, in alesuada neque.
          Duis mauris enim, porttitor sit amet mi a, ultricies egestas nisl. Nullam vitae urna efficitur, cursus nisl sit amet, molestie orci. Duis et nulla tortor
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
      <p>2016-01-12 Footer comes here</p>
      <p>
        <?php include_once( "php/footer.php") ?>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="bottomBar">
      <p>
        <?php include_once( "php/bottomBar.php") ?>
      </p>
      <p>Any other snippet might come here, either a link to somewhere or anything else.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the `overflow:hidden` on the container that makes it invisible. You could use another clear floats technique instead.

```
.menu{  
  margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  background-color: #333;
  list-style-type: none;    
}
.menu:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/war6qcvs/2/)**